# Appending a Custom Component to an Already Existing Div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events, components

I'm currently trying to write a method that reads in data from a `CSV` file and converts each line of the `CSV` into a card component from `material-ui`, but I can't seem to figure out how to go about doing this. Every time I try to append the html needed to correctly define the Card component to a div, nothing ends up happening, but I am able to use the `div.innerHTML += "additional html"` syntax just fine. I did find a *temporary* workaround that uses `ReactDOM`, but I wanted to find a more permanent solution since `ReactDOM` is outdated. Below is the code that I'm currently working with:

Div I would like to append to:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="cards"></div>
  );
}
```

Code for parsing the `CSV`:

```
import './App.css';
import Card from './Components/Card';
import '../src/Data/parsing.js';
import Papa from 'papaparse'; 
import ReadString from './Parser';

const { readString } = usePapaParse();

let card_list = document.getElementById('card_list');

const handleReadString = () => {
    const csvString = data;

    readString(csvString, {
      worker: true,
      complete: (results) => {
        console.log('---------------------------');
        console.log(results);
        console.log('---------------------------');

        results.data.forEach((cardData) => {
          console.log(cardData)
          const cardElement = <Card description={cardData.at(0)} />;
          card_list.innerHTML += "<Card />";
        });

      },
    });
  };
```

As described above, I've been trying to figure out how to append this html with the `div.innerHTML += "additional html"` syntax but that just doesn't seem to work. I have been able to get this to function with the `ReactDOM.render()` syntax, but it only renders a couple of cards then quits on me, and I keep receiving notice that this syntax is dated, so I wanted to see about finding a better solution